# IntentService vs Service

Tags: android, android-service

I need to make an alarm in my app that starts playing music at user specified time. It should start by user interaction, restored once Android has killed the process or phone has been restarted. I am new to services so I have a quick question: what should I use? Intent Service, Service or something else? Sure I can do it with service but what is the best approach?

P.S. It must start it's own playback that is retrieved from internet.

Comment: I read it and I still am not sure. I guess IntentService but maybe someone could explain more accurately

Comment: Please edit your question to explain **completely and precisely** what you are "not sure" about after having read those answers.